# Can fn.constructor be different from Object.getPrototype(fn).constructor?

Tags: javascript, object, constructor, prototype

I am writing a program that that serializes objects. As part of that, I need to get the class  from an instance so I can create a new instance in the future. I noticed that I can either call `fn.constructor` or `Object.getPrototypeOf(fn).constructor` to get the class that the instance came from. For example:

```js
class Foo {}
const myFoo = new Foo();

const constructor1 = myFoo.constructor;
const constructor2 = Object.getPrototypeOf(myFoo).constructor;
```

In the above, `constructor1` and `constructor2` seem to always be the same unless I manually set them to some other value. Is there a circumstance in which these values would be different?

Comment: What do you mean by "*unless I manually set them to some other value*"?

Comment: "*Is there a circumstance in which these values would be different?*" - are you only taking about instances of `class`es or about arbitrary objects?

Comment: "*I am writing a program that that serializes objects.*" - I would recommend to call `.toJSON()` for that, not rely on some constructor magic. An object might hold some internal state that you cannot restore with knowing the specific class.

Comment: Why are you using `class` syntax and `Object.getPrototypeOf` in a question tagged [tag:ecmascript-5]?

Comment: 1. Like obj.constructor = 'foo', 2, arbitrary objects, 3. The program I am working on knows the classes which is why it can restore the state, 4. This is my mistake, I will remove the tag

Comment: If you know the classes, and there is only a limited set of them, I would not even use the `.constructor` but just give each class an identifier as a separate property, which can then be used to select the class for restoration.

Answer (score 1):

You have already identified the circumstance when they are different.

When you call `Object.getPrototypeOf(myFoo).constructor`, you are accessing the `constructor` property of the prototypical instance of `Foo`.

If you have an instance of Foo that doesn't directly have `constructor` defined, accessing it "passes through" `myFoo` and hits `Foo.prototype`. So, the only time the two would differ is if you manually redefined the `constructor` property on `myFoo`, like you said:

```js
myFoo.constructor = NotFoo
```

In this case, JavaScript creates a property directly on the `myFoo` instance, so accessing `myFoo.constructor` never "passes through" to `Foo.prototype`.

The interesting case is when you are dealing with inheritance:

```js
class Foo1 {}
class Foo2 extends Foo1{}

const myFoo2 = new Foo2()

const proto1 = Object.getPrototypeOf(myFoo2)
const proto2 = Object.getPrototypeOf(proto1)

proto1.constructor  // Foo2
proto2.constructor  // Foo1
```

Comment: "*the only time the two would differ*" - not really :-)

Comment: @Bergi what do you mean?

Comment: I mean there are many other ways to modify the program so that they are not the same

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a circumstance in which these values would be different?

Sure, and not just those where you did manually set the `.constructor` object on an instance.

There also exist "normal" objects with such a `.constructor` property, namely prototype objects like `Foo.prototype`.

Another case are objects without a prototype, like `Object.create(null)` or `Object.prototype`, where one of your expressions causes an exception but the other works.

Then there might be (construed) cases where `.constructor` is a getter that returns different values when invoked on an instance vs on the prototype object itself.

Finally, don't forget that `constructor1` and `constructor2` might be the same value, but not necessarily functions as you expect.